# Div contents not rendering when scrolling horizontally and adding background color

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Why is it that the contents of my div are not rendered when I am scrolling horizontally?

When I shrink down my screen, the scrollbar appears correctly. But when I do scroll, the content that was outside of the view-port do not get rendered.

What I have figured out so far is that it has something to do with adding background color to the div. Whenever I remove the background color property, the problem is gone and the overflow works correctly.

How could I implement this to work correctly with the overflow and background color?

I want the scrollbar to only be on the main container, as this example is simplified. My actual code contains multiple 'item-containers' and I would like them to all scroll together.

```css
.main-container {
  overflow: auto;
}

.items-container {
  display: flex;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: rgb(33, 37, 41);
  color: white;
}

.item {
  max-width: 250px;
  min-width: 250px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">

  <div class="items-container">
    <div class="item">
      <label>Hello World 1</label>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <label>Hello World 2</label>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <label>Hello World 3</label>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <label>Hello World 4</label>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <label>Hello World 5</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, The thing is the flex-items are not wrapping into new row; and items-container is blocking element to max width of the parent. As parent div(.main-container) has overflow auto this leads the child to render unexpectedly.

So there are 2 ways to fix this.

One is adding `display: flex;` to the `.main-container` div.

**or**

Another add css `width: max-content;` in `.items-container` class

```css
.main-container {
  overflow: auto;
  /* display: flex; */ /*this works also*/ 
}

.items-container {
  display: flex;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: rgb(33, 37, 41);
  color: white;
  width: max-content;
}

.item {
  max-width: 250px;
  min-width: 250px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">

  <div class="items-container">
    <div class="item">
      <label>Hello World 1</label>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <label>Hello World 2</label>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <label>Hello World 3</label>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <label>Hello World 4</label>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <label>Hello World 5</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Changing `display: flex` to `display: inline-flex` in your .image-container will ensure the overflow is visible on scroll

```css
.main-container {
    overflow: auto; 
}


.items-container {
    display: inline-flex; /*add this*/
    border-radius: 8px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: rgb(33, 37, 41);
    color: white;
}

.item {
    max-width: 250px;
    min-width: 250px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">

    <div class="items-container">
        <div class="item">
            <label>Hello World 1</label>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <label>Hello World 2</label>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <label>Hello World 3</label>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <label>Hello World 4</label>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <label>Hello World 5</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works on the example, but I was hoping for something that enables scroll only on the main container. So that when I add multiple div's, or multiple 'item-containers', the all scroll together. I will update the question to include this

Comment: Does changing .items-container to `display: inline-flex` help?

Comment: Yes it does! Thanks so much! Please update your answer so I can mark it as correct

Comment: this also works well.